# Multiple window.open not working in IE

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, href

I've got an ahref that when clicked, changes the content of 3 iFrames. Here's the code:

```
<a href='weekone.php' target='weekone' onclick='window.open("weektwo.php","weektwo"); window.open("weekthree.php","weekthree")'>Link</a>
```

Now this works perfectly in Firefox, Safari etc but doesn't work in IE. Can anyone shed some light on this problem for me please? I can't use a Javascript because I'm working within a PHP framework and the iFrame links are called from the database.

**UPDATE**

It appears the issue lies with spaces in the URLs called from window.open! As I'm calling info from a database (ie - "weektwo.php?Name=Bob and Dave") how can I get around this??

Comment: Any chance you can update the question with the actual ouput that is being sent to IE? (replace any actual URL's with fake ones)

Comment: You're missing a ; after the 2nd window.open. could be the problem. and by the way, you ARE using javascript.

Comment: I'm not sure the missing ; will be a problem on it's own - but I would try putting a "return true" at the end of the onclick (which *would* require an ; at the end of the 2nd window.open)

Comment: @freefaller Is that better? Thanks.
And Eric, where exactly? I've added one here "weekthree);" but it still doesn't work...

Comment: @freefaller Not 100% sure what you mean. Could you give an example please?

Comment: @PhilHowell, yes, much better. When talking about a problem at the browser, it's always better to show what's reaching the browser (as a direct copy/paste if possible) as otherwise it's guess work as to exactly what the php is producing

Comment: As IE being a pain in the ..., try playing around with it, like writing "javascript:" before the commands, like freefaler said return true or the best just write it in a seperate fucntion and just set the function on click.

Comment: @eric.itzhak How do I do that exactly? I don't really know what I'm doing...

Answer (score 0):

On the back of the comments, try adding "return true;" to the end of the onclick (untested)...

```
<a href='weekone.php' target='weekone' onclick='window.open("weektwo.php","weektwo"); window.open("weekthree.php","weekthree"); return true;'>Link</a>
```

**UPDATE**

In light of the updated question, try "HTML Encoding" the query strings using the PHP function "htmlentities".

I'm basing the following on your original (pre-edited) code.  So in this case I apologise for asking you to edit it, but I *did* ask you to show exactly what was being sent to the browser...

```
<a href='weekone.php?Name=<?=htmlentities($i[Name])?>' target='<?=$i[Name]?> weekone' onclick='window.open("weektwo.php?Name=<?=htmlentities($i[Name])?>","<?=$i[Name]?> weektwo"); window.open("weekthree.php?Name=<?=htmlentities($i[Name])?>","<?=$i[Name]?> weekthree")'>Link</a>
```

**UPDATE 2** (due to me being stupid)

It shouldn't be "HTML Encoding" it should be "URL Encoding" using "urlencode"...

```
<a href='weekone.php?Name=<?=urlencode($i[Name])?>' target='<?=$i[Name]?> weekone' onclick='window.open("weektwo.php?Name=<?=urlencode($i[Name])?>","<?=$i[Name]?> weektwo"); window.open("weekthree.php?Name=<?=urlencode($i[Name])?>","<?=$i[Name]?> weekthree")'>Link</a>
```

Comment: OK - I think the problem is that you're hitting IE "popup blocker"... testing on IE8 I get the first window and then the "pop-up blocked" message at the top of the client window.  My guess is that you're not going to get around this one (without asking the user to allow pop-up).

Comment: Even thought I'm opening in an iFrame?!

Comment: Doh... sorry, I'm an arse... I didn't notice it was IFrames... back to the drawing board

Comment: @PhilHowell - sorry, I don't have an answer.  Like numespascal, I have test on IE6 IE8 (inc Compatibility mode) and IE9 (inc Compatibility Mode) and don't see a problem - unfortunately I do not have IE7 to test with

Comment: @PhilHowell - can you just confirm one thing for me... when you say it's "not working", can be specific. Is the fault the the iframes are not loading the correct thing, or that the iframes are not even *attempting* to load anything?

Comment: It's loading the first iFrame, but the 2 called from window.open are blank. When I look at the source it says <html></html>

Comment: Running out of ideas. All I can suggest is that you double check that the correct page is actually being requested in the "other" iframes.  The href of the link will assume a relative directory to the current page, maybe try making the weektwo.php an absolute path (i.e. if the file is in sub-directory "subdir" make the path "/subdir/weektwo.php")

Comment: I was thinking there might be a difference in the relative path that the "href" of the link might take, as opposed to the path that the window.open parameter. However, it appears they work correctly. Sorry Phil, I'm out of ideas, and cannot afford to spend any more time looking into it. Good luck finding the solution (no doubt it will be a facepalm moment when you figure it out, they normally are!)

Comment: I've discovered the issue!! See my updated post. Hopefully you may be able to help.

Comment: Phil, you numpty... didn't I tell you to copy/paste what was being sent to the browser!! ;-) Will update my answer

Comment: Thanks so much for that but I'm afraid it's still not working :-(

Comment: Ack, sorry, it shouldn't HTML Encoding, it should be URL encoding (it's turning into a very long day!!)... will update

Comment: Getting there now. Thanks so much :-) The only problem is that the called URL can't GET the correct data from the URL in order to query the database as the spaces have been replaced with +'s... eek, I effing hate IE.

Answer (score 0):

What version of IE?

Tested on IE 8 and this worked perfectly.

```
<a href='test.htm' target='weekone' onclick='window.open("test.htm","weektwo"); window.open("test.htm","weekthree")'>Link</a>

<iframe name='weekone' id='weekone' width=100 height=100></iframe>

<iframe name='weektwo' id='weektwo' width=100 height=100></iframe>

<iframe name='weekthree' id='weekthree' width=100 height=100></iframe>
```

Comment: My first frame is loading perfectly. It's the two window.open commands that aren't...

Comment: Sorry, no IE9 here. But this seems to work ok with older versions of IE.

Comment: Most php libraries have methods to escape a url. Those spaces should come as '%20' i think.

Comment: That looks amazing but I have absolutely no idea how to implement this... :-S

Comment: Pass your php variable through that function. Something like <a href='<?=urlencode("weektwo.php?Name=Bob and Dave") ...

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to open links in an `<iframe>`, it's probably easier to do

```
document.querySelector('iframe[name="weekone"]').src='test.htm';
document.querySelector('iframe[name="weektwo"]').src='test.htm';
document.querySelector('iframe[name="weekthree"]').src='test.htm';
```

(I've used [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelector) because it's the easiest, but of course you can use document.getElementById or whatever way you want to get a reference to the `<iframe>`.)

Comment: How exactly do I implement that please?

Comment: Try something like `<a href='weekone.php' target='weekone' onclick='document.querySelector('iframe[name="weekone"]').src='weekone.php';document.querySelector('iframe[name="weektwo"]').src='weektwo.php';
document.querySelector('iframe[name="weekthree"]').src='weekthree.php';return false
'>Link</a>`